# shutil says subfolder is in use so it can't move it and the program crashes but everything is moved successfully

Tags: python, shutil

I am using shutil to move a folder that contains a bunch of stuff my program was using right before I give the move command. Everything I care about has been unloaded from memory at this point so every single file is successfully moved to the target folder as expected. Cryptically, a problematic subfolder remains behind (even though one like it is created at the target location) and the program throws the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
    'C:\\Users\\Ze\\PycharmProjects\\Ploutos\\ProductList\\Unedited\\1005001769427465\\Images'
```

The folder I am moving is the number ID one, which contains the problematic 'Images' folder.

**Edit:** As far as I can tell no program other than my own and Pycharm is using the folder. Could it be Pycharm when it attempts to re-index the file?

Relevant code:

```
def move_product_to_edited(product_id):
    global products_edited_during_session_counter

    unedited_products_path = application_path + '\\ProductList\\Unedited\\'

    edited_products_path = application_path + '\\ProductList\\Edited\\'

    # if the product has not yet been moved, move it
    if os.path.exists(unedited_products_path + str(product_id)):
        shutil.move(unedited_products_path + str(product_id), edited_products_path + str(product_id))
```

How can I try to further debug this? I have no idea how to check why the folder is still in use.

Comment: Well, can you identify another program that might be accessing the folder? For example, Windows (Explorer)? (Do you have a window open that is viewing the folder?) It seems like your question is more to do with Windows than with programming.

Comment: That's the thing, nothing other than the program itself is using the folder. Could it be Pycharm? If so, what do I do?

Comment: The error is probably occurring when `shutil.move()` is trying to delete the folder (and the files in it) after copying its contents. If some other program has the directory open (like pycharm or explorer) you can get this message.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help! Turns out it was PyCharm itself. The folder was marked as a resource folder so I guess it kept track of everything in it to re-index it as soon as necessary. Thanks!